# Session Token Authentication Security

Tags: angularjs, authentication, token

I need some advice regarding using session tokens to authenticate users. I am building an AngularJS app which uses an API to tie in with the backend. I am only building the front end, not the backend. The documentation states that all calls to the API have a session token attached in the body of the request (POST).

1. I would like to know about the security of storing this token in localStorage. That is where I am storing it now and retrieving and attaching it to each API request. After login, the server sends the session token in the body and I save it from there.
2. There is no documentation about an x-access-token header that should be sent with the request made to the server. It is not being checked server side. What are the implications of this? I feel that it is susceptible to attacks without this added layer of security.

My main concern is the security of this setup. I want to know what the best setup is to make sure this app is as secure as possible and recommend changes to the way the backend is setup to facilitate this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tell, you are only working on the UI part and not the backend. It is up to the backend team to ensure headers are properly evaluated and security is enforced (btw request headers do not belong to request body). Just put the token into the `x-access-token` header as they tell.

Storing the token inside the `localStorage` gives you a little more control over the cookie: You will not accidentally send it to unnecessary URLs. However, older browsers do not support it - you may need to use a shim for that.

In a case of SPA, you may consider not storing the token at all: It could be fetched each time your application is accessed and then stored within a service in angularjs, but it depends how your fetch/login operation is implemented (is it always interactive, how long does it take, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use $cookies rather than localstorage. As localstorage does not support some legacy browser.
I am using cookies to store token in my project